# INSERT where doesn't exist in php script, comparing 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have a script that runs every 5 minutes and selects the data from a table on server 1 and an  identical table on server2. This is a workaround for replication, essentially, since we don't have that option currently.

The script is successful but I've realized that it misses records sometimes, for whatever reason. The current script selects all records from the destination table, stores the max primary key, selects all data from the source table and then inserts anything with a greater Primary key into the dest. table.

I'd like to modify the script slightly and instead of using max id, just say "if a row has an primary key that doesn't exist in the destination table, insert that row there."

Again these are cloned tables so the structure is the same and they both use AI Primary Keys.

Here's the current working script:

```
$latest_result = $conn2->query("SELECT MAX(`SESSIONID`) FROM 
`ambition`.`session`");
$latest_row = $latest_result->fetch_row();
$latest_session_id = $latest_row[0];

 //Select All rows from the source phone database
 $source_data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM 
 `cdrdb`.`session` WHERE `SESSIONID` > $latest_session_id");

 // Loop on the results
 while($source = $source_data->fetch_assoc()) {

 // Check if row exists in destination phone database
 $row_exists = $conn2->query("SELECT SESSIONID FROM 
 ambition.session WHERE SESSIONID = '".$source['SESSIONID']."' ") or 
 die(mysqli_error($conn2));

 //if query returns false, rows don't exist with that new ID.
 if ($row_exists->num_rows == 0){

 //Insert new rows into ambition.session
 $stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO ambition.session (SESSIONID, 
 SESSIONTYPE,CALLINGPARTYNO,FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,
 DIALPLANNAME,TERMINATIONREASONCODE  //etc. There are a lot of columns so I 
 ommitted the others
```

Is there a way I can slightly modify this to just insert what doesn't exist rather than relying on the MAX ID?

Or is there something here that would be a culprit as to why it's missing records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `INSERT INTO SELECT` and check if value is already in target:

```
INSERT INTO trg_table (cols)
SELECT cols
FROM src_table s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trg_table t WHERE t.id = s.id);
```

Comment: Looks like the OP wants something that will work across two different connections.

Comment: How would I have to modify that in this case, though, since each table is on a different server? That's why I have the statements for each table in it's own query

Comment: @TomN. Has MySQL something like Databaselink or linked server?

Comment: There is a [federated storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html) that allows this. However this may require recompilation of binaries and configuration changes.

Comment: I don't believe so. I had to use a tool to copy over the initial sync and Ive been using scripts like this ever since

Comment: @Phylogenesis I believe we had tried something with federated tables but our restrictions on the source database wouldn't allow us to. WE basically have admin Read priveleges, but can only create tables in a 'testing' schema

Comment: @lad2025 The logic of your answer is definitely what I'm looking for, I'm just curious the best way to split it into different statements so that they can each use the respective connection

Comment: @TomN. In that kind of scenario, where direct connection is not possible, I would probably use some kind of ETL/integration tool like: SSIS/Pentaho Data Integrator or similiar.